# What is the average cost of hosting a django app?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, hosting, digital-ocean

Due to current RBI guidelines on recurring payments for standing instructions I am unable to use Heroku which is great for small apps. Therefore I have to choose other platoforms. I have narrowed down my choice to two platforms **aws** and **digital ocean**.

**overview of my django website :**

The website which I made for my client is not that big. In this website a user registers, chooses some plan and then book an intructor to teach him/ her driving. A user after loging in has to accept an agreement and also has an udate plan page. Thats it on the user side. Now I use celery which uses redis, to send emails such as otp, registration successful, change password, contracts and updated contracts (the contracts' email are send both to the client and the user as per the clients demand). As you can see I have to use celery and redis because there is a lot email work that has to be done by the website. And the **database** i am using is **Postgresql**.

Now comming to traffic, we cannot predict what will be the number of visitors on the site, but we accept maximum of 10 registrations per month.

Therefore I want to know what will be the monthly cost of running this django website on **aws** and **digital ocean**. Not an accurate cost but atleast an average assumption will be helpful.

**Note** the redis server is neccessary otherwise it will really slow down the website. And the database is Postgresql.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So AWS is a vast ocean and it has lot of options to solve any problem. With that being said you can host your application starting from 0$ to 100s of $s. If your account is new then you can host your application on [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) and don't have to pay anything.

If your looking for cost efficient solution then AWS Lightsail is another option. Lightsail offers fixed monthly cost resources and is good way to start with AWS.

EC2 instances is also an option but I would suggest to host it on Fargate (less maintenance). And use AWS Elasticache for your Redis requirements. Using managed services will cost you more but it's reliable and highly scalable solution compared to self hosted solutions.

Depending on which services you go with, calculate your cost via this calculator https://calculator.aws/